# Adding a custom function to twig in OROcrm

Tags: php, symfony, twig, orocrm

I've created an extension with my custom function in it.

```
    class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
    {
        private $_container;

        public function __construct($container)
        {
            $this->_container = $container;
        }

        public function getFunctions()
        {
            return [
                new \Twig_SimpleFunction('autologin', [$this, 'autologin'], ['is_safe' => ['all']])
            ];
        }

        public function autologin($customer, $url)
        {
            return sprintf('');
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'xxx_app_extension';
        }
    }
```

I've added it to services.yml:

```
    xxx_opportunity.twig.helper:
    class: 'OpportunityBundle\Twig\AppExtension'
    public: false
    arguments:
        - '@service_container'
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

When I look if it is found by ORO by doing "php bin/console debug:twig", I can see my custom function appear in the list. When I try to implement it in an email template using the email template editor in OROcrm, I get the following error:

```
The template for xxxx has syntax error: Unknown "autologin" function at line 18.
```

This has been doing my head in for way too long, anyone with a solution?

---

Update:

```
$instance = new \Oro\Bundle\EmailBundle\Provider\EmailRenderer(${($_ = isset($this->services['oro_email
$instance->addExtension(${($_ = isset($this->services['oro_ui.twig.html_tag']) ? $this->services['oro_u
$instance->addExtension(${($_ = isset($this->services['oro_config.twig.config_extension']) ? $this->ser
$instance->addExtension(${($_ = isset($this->services['oro_ui.twig.extension.formatter']) ? $this->serv
$instance->addExtension(${($_ = isset($this->services['oro_locale.twig.address']) ? $this->services['or
$instance->addExtension(${($_ = isset($this->services['oro_locale.twig.date_time']) ? $this->services['
$instance->addExtension(${($_ = isset($this->services['oro_entity.twig.extension.entity']) ? $this->ser
$instance->addExtension(${($_ = isset($this->services['twig.extension.intl']) ? $this->services['twig.e
$instance->addExtension(${($_ = isset($this->services['oro_locale.twig.date_time_organization']) ? $thi
$instance->addExtension(${($_ = isset($this->services['oro_calendar.twig.dateformat']) ? $this->service
$instance->addExtension(${($_ = isset($this->services['oro_calendar.twig.recurrence']) ? $this->service
$instance->addExtension(${($_ = isset($this->services['oro_currency.twig.currency']) ? $this->services[
$instance->addExtension(${($_ = isset($this->services['twig.extension.routing']) ? $this->services['twi
```

This is what the compiler ends up with for getOroEmail_EmailRendererService.php, it is lacking my extension as you can see. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the namespace `OpportunityBundle\Twig` also present in the class `AppExtension`?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with the class itself.

Comment: Everything looks OK to me as well in your example code

Comment: JFYI emails templates doesn't have access to all twig functions and filters, only to narrow set

Comment: @SerhiiPolishchuk Howso? Surely symfony will inject his custom extension class or not?

Comment: @DarkBee and this is where I think the issue lies. If I take a look at what symfony autogenerated for getOroEmail_EmailRendererService.php it lacks my extension. See the edit

Comment: You should ask at slack channel, or in github issues to core team, I don’t remember how and where, but I’m sure that only few extensions os available for emails.

Answer (score 0):

Twig for rendering files and twig for rendering email templates are not the same instance. ORO CRM kind of extends Twig functionality for rendering email templates, look at `Oro\Bundle\EmailBundle\Provider\EmailRendered`. I was unable to find any tag related to this thing so you might need CompilerPass to add extension for EmailRenderer.